# Show that $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ can have arbitrarily many solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Equivalently, show that for every $m$, there exists some $n$ such that $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ has at least $m$ solutions.

Would appreciate any help or hints. I have a feeling this may be a pretty simple proof, but right now I am stuck. Thanks!

Comment: You can choose $x$ to be $\pm 1$ modulo each prime factor of $n$. (Two options for each prime factor) Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to show that each possible choice does in fact give you a solution for $x$.

Comment: There are always at least $m$ solutions, but not necessarily at least $m$ modulo $n$. Take $n=2$. Then infinitely many integers $x=2k+1$ are solutions (but only $1$ solution modulo $2$).

Comment: But the OP is only asking for the existence of such an $n$. For example, when $m=3$ we can pick $n=15$ and $1^2\equiv 4^2\equiv 11^2 \pmod{15}$

Comment: @Dylan How does CRT guarantee the solutions are different?

Comment: @cr001 They have different remainders modulo some prime factor of $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

Let $k$ be some positive integer such that $2^k \geq m$. Let $p_1, p_2, p_3, \cdots, p_k$ be $k$ distinct odd primes. (It's possible to choose $k$ distinct odd primes since there are infinitely many primes.)

Consider $n = p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k$, and look at the system of congruences
$$\begin{align*}
x \equiv \pm 1 & \pmod{p_1} \\
x \equiv \pm 1 & \pmod{p_2} \\
x \equiv \pm 1 & \pmod{p_3} \\
& \vdots \\
x \equiv \pm 1 & \pmod{p_k}
\end{align*}$$
where we choose either $+1$ or $-1$ for each prime. There are two choices for each prime, and so there are $2^k \geq m$ possible systems that can arise in this way.

by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, each one of these $2^k$ systems has some solution $x$ modulo $p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k = n$. No two systems give us the same value for $x$ modulo $n$, since if $x_1$ and $x_2$ arise from two different systems of congruences then there is some prime $p_i$ such that
$$ \begin{align*}
x_1 & \equiv \pm 1 \pmod {p_i} && \text{ but } & x_2 & \equiv \mp 1 \pmod {p_i}
\end{align*} $$

(i.e. $x_1$ and $x_2$ have different remainders modulo some prime factor of $n$)

This shows that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not congruent modulo $n$, and so we in fact get $2^k$ *distinct* values of $x$ by looking at systems of congruences of the form given above.

Now for any such solution $x$, we have that
$$\begin{align*}
x^2 \equiv (\pm 1)^2 & \equiv 1 \pmod{p_1} \\
x^2 \equiv (\pm 1)^2 & \equiv 1 \pmod{p_2} \\
x^2 \equiv (\pm 1)^2 & \equiv 1 \pmod{p_3} \\
& \vdots \\
x^2 \equiv (\pm 1)^2 & \equiv 1 \pmod{p_k}
\end{align*}$$

and so we see (since the $p_i$ are pairwise relatively prime) that
$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Thus each of the $2^k \geq m$ possible values for $x$ are a solution to $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Comment: More concisely, $U(n) \cong U(p_1) \times \cdots \times U(p_k)$  and each factor has even order and so has an element of order $2$. This gives you at least $2^k$ elements of order $2$ in $U(n)$.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!